# How do I decrypt encrypted text?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I found code that permits me to encrypt and decrypt a text:

```
cipherData = textBox2->Text;
plainbytes = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(cipherData);

plainKey = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes("0123456789abcdef");

desObj->Key = plainKey;

desObj->Mode = CipherMode::CBC;

desObj->Padding = PaddingMode::PKCS7;

MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();
CryptoStream^ cs = gcnew CryptoStream(ms,desObj->CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode::Write);

cs->Write(plainbytes,0,plainbytes->Length);
cs->Close();

chipherbytes = ms->ToArray();
ms->Close();

textBox3->Text = Encoding::ASCII->GetString(chipherbytes);

//decripto
     
MemoryStream^ ms1 = gcnew MemoryStream(chipherbytes);
CryptoStream^ cs1 = gcnew CryptoStream(ms1,desObj->CreateDecryptor(),CryptoStreamMode::Read);

cs1->Read(chipherbytes,0,chipherbytes->Length);
plainbytes2 = ms1->ToArray();
cs1->Close();
ms1->Close();

textBox4->Text = Encoding::ASCII->GetString(plainbytes2);
```

It is perfect and works very well. The problem is that I wish decrypt a previous encrypted text, starting from ASCII and not from MemoryStream.

I tried the code in this way:

```
cipherData = textBox2->Text;
plainbytes = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(cipherData);

plainKey = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes("0123456789abcdef");

desObj->Key = plainKey;

desObj->Mode = CipherMode::CBC;

desObj->Padding = PaddingMode::PKCS7;

MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();
CryptoStream^ cs = gcnew CryptoStream(ms,desObj->CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode::Write);

cs->Write(plainbytes,0,plainbytes->Length);
cs->Close();

chipherbytes = ms->ToArray();
ms->Close();

textBox3->Text = Encoding::ASCII->GetString(chipherbytes);

//DECRYPTION CODE
     

cipherData = textBox3->Text;
chipherbytes = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(cipherData);
     
MemoryStream^ ms1 = gcnew MemoryStream(chipherbytes);
CryptoStream^ cs1 = gcnew CryptoStream(ms1,desObj->CreateDecryptor(),CryptoStreamMode::Read);

cs1->Read(chipherbytes,0,chipherbytes->Length);
plainbytes2 = ms1->ToArray();
cs1->Close();
ms1->Close();

textBox4->Text = Encoding::ASCII->GetString(plainbytes2);
```

But when I try the code I receive this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
> 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in
> mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional Information: The padding is invalid and can not be removed.

**EDIT 1:**

I switched off the wordwrap property and now I get a new error:

> Eccezione non gestita di tipo 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' in >mscorlib.dll
> Informazioni aggiuntive: Lunghezza dei dati da decrittografare non valida.
>
> (An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' >occurred in mscorlib.dll
> Additional information: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.)

Comment: BTW—`textBox2->Text` will hold Unicode characters, not ASCII. So, you might want to convert using `Encoding::Unicode` or `Encoding::UTF8` instead. That will avoid data loss due to ASCII being a smaller character set—so small that it's scarcely used anymore (except by mistake).

Comment: I changed all Encoding::ASCII to Encoding::UTF8 without success, I get the same error

Comment: Using Unicode instead of ASCII it functions, but there are many errors and data loss on the decrypted text

Comment: In order to not loss data I used System::Convert::ToBase64String and I solved the problems. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

Iused System::Convert::ToBase64String to write the encrypted text correctly into the textbox avoiding data loss; then I loaded the text from the textbox using System::Convert::FromBase64String

```
         //ENCRYPTION CODE

         cipherData = textBox2->Text;
         plainbytes = Encoding::Unicode->GetBytes(cipherData);

         plainKey = Encoding::Unicode->GetBytes("0123456789abcdef");

         desObj->Key = plainKey;

         desObj->Mode = CipherMode::CBC;

         desObj->Padding = PaddingMode::PKCS7;

         MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();
         CryptoStream^ cs = gcnew CryptoStream(ms,desObj->CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode::Write);

         cs->Write(plainbytes,0,plainbytes->Length);
         cs->Close();

         chipherbytes = ms->ToArray();
         ms->Close();

         textBox3->Text = System::Convert::ToBase64String(chipherbytes);

         //DECRYPTION CODE


         chipherbytes = System::Convert::FromBase64String(textBox3->Text);

         MemoryStream^ ms1 = gcnew MemoryStream(chipherbytes);
         CryptoStream^ cs1 = gcnew CryptoStream(ms1,desObj->CreateDecryptor(),CryptoStreamMode::Read);

         cs1->Read(chipherbytes,0,chipherbytes->Length);
         plainbytes2 = ms1->ToArray();
         cs1->Close();
         ms1->Close();

         textBox4->Text = Encoding::Unicode->GetString(plainbytes2);
```

Comment: In order to help other people with this problem who look at this question in the future, please explain what the problem was, and what you changed in order to make it work.